# Chrome allows ajax going to http foreign origin where firefox does not - why?

Tags: spring, http, https, cors

I have a JSP with javascript code, running on a server with HTTPS. In this JavaScript I trigger a request to **another (local) webserver** like this:

```
let url = 'http:/localhost:3111/doSomePost';
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
        processData: false,
        data: uint8array
    })
```

This requires CrossOrigin to be enabled on the local webserver in order to work - I configured that part and it works.

But it only works in Chrome. Not in Firefox.

Firefox will give me this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://localhost:3111/doSomePost. (Reason: CORS
>   request did not succeed).

I can see in the network tab of firefox devtools, that firefox does not even bother to send the preflight request (the OPTIONS request). So Firefox just decides it won't send that request (and I suspect it to be because that local webserver protocol is HTTP).

I have now changed my local webserver to use HTTPS using a self-signed certificate as described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate

Now, it works in Firefox and Chrome (after I manually add the certificate which is not valid).

I just wonder why chrome has no problem but firefox does.

**UPDATE: corrected minor typo in error message**

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a better solution. Instead of switching the local webserver to HTTPS in order to get firefox working, I changed the above request to:

```
let url = 'http:/localhost:3111/doSomePost';
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: jsonWithBase64encodedData
    })
```

This now qualifies as so called "Simple request" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) again, and is being treated in a similar, and most importantly, working way in all browsers.